# in OSPF routing, how routers inside an area get to know the routing outside the area?

Tags: networking, router, routing

in OSPF routing, the information exchanged between routers in an OSPF area  is link state.inside an area. Through the link state information, each router can construct a routing table inside the area.

however, how can the routers inside an area know the routing table outside the area or even outside the autonomous system?

it is through ABR and BGP border routers that informs the outside routing information to the routers. So finally, the ABR and BGP Border routers still need to flood to the routers inside an area or AS that "which outside IP networks can be reached via me".

so does this mean, the ABR or BGP border routers still need to send routing table information but not link state?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've dealt with OSPF, but won't the border router (ABR) include itself as the default (0.0.0.0) route in the link state advertisement? In that case, just the border router would need to keep information outside of the AS.

Answer (score 0):

The protocols operate independently of each other. These routes are then installed into a device's routing table and selected based on the protocol's administrative distance, among other things. OSPF advertisements will only be discovered by other OSPF participating interconnected routers in the network, like with any other interior gateway routing protocol.

Any traffic not matching a route supplied through OSPF would go via the default route (0.0.0.0) and leave your network at the router which advertised the default route. This is done by telling OSPF to advertise the default route with the `default-information originate` command (Cisco) when you are configuring your OSPF area, but only on the edge router.

If your edge router also happens to participate in BGP, then a BGP route may be selected to forward the packets on, but this depends on what the routing table looks like.

*I must add, this was a bit of a revision session for me and I've never read up on BGP. That said, I'm pretty confident what I've written is correct. Also, this question is **very** network oriented. There is a special stack exchange for such questions https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/*